# How to automatically go to a hyperlink by batch processessing

Tags: hyperlink, batch-processing, double-click

How to automatically go to a hyperlink by batch processessing ?

I have good knowledge about batch processing but I dont know if anyone can open a specified link via .bat file...

**EDIT:** I want to make a batch file(.bat) and on double clicking on that I want to open a specified link in my browser..

So is it possible ? Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it with the help of:

```
 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com
```

-courtesy of @Rainer.R

Answer (score 0):

You can try Wget for Windows - http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm, this works great.

Comment: @Rainer.R-Hey I think u misunderstood my question..I have edited my question...is that what you understood ?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood that. "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com works on my computer, perhaps that helps